# UnsafeBufferPointer wont work when referenced with pointer from another class instance

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I have two pieces of code:

```
// Non-working one
public func put(path: String) -> Int64 {
    owner.id += 1

    writeBatch.put(path.data(), value: Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &owner.id, count: 1)))

    return owner.id
}
```

And

```
// Working one
public func requestId() -> Int64 {
    owner.id += 1

    return owner.id
}

public func put(path: String) -> Int64 {
    var id = requestId()

    writeBatch.put(path.data(), value: Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &id, count: 1)))

    return id
}
```

The difference between these two pieces of code is only within UnsafeBufferPointer (start parameter). The trick is that non-working version references value in another class instance while the working version references local parameter.

I don't get it, why in a world this could ever not work? I've spent a week identifying this bug

Thank you in advance!

*Edit*

Forgot to mention what the issue is. The issue has the following effect: `writeBatch` receives empty Data, i.e. it is filled with zeros, while the `owner.id` is always non-zero. Plus the issue is only reproduced in release build of application and works fine for development build

Comment: Please describe _not work_. What happens when you use your _Non-working one_?

Comment: Oh, sorry, `writeBatch` receives empty Data, i.e. filled with zeros, while the `owner.id` is always non-zero. Plus the issue is only reproduced in release build of application and works fine under development env

Comment: Thanks for the description. I'll try to write a little explanation with some code later (not so long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but you may be hitting this feature of Swift `inout` parameter:

### [Function Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID362)

> #### In-Out Parameters
>
> In-out parameters are passed as follows:
>
> 1. When the function is called, the value of the argument is copied.
> 2. In the body of the function, the copy is modified.
> 3. When the function returns, the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument.

Having this *copy-in copy-out* behavior in mind, please check your code again.

```
writeBatch.put(path.data(), value: Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &owner.id, count: 1)))
```

When calling the initializer `UnsafeBufferPointer.init(start:count:)`, Swift creates a copy of of the `inout` parameter `&owner.id`.

And then, Swift invokes the initializer with the address of the temporary copy.

After finishing the initializer, Swift may release the region of the copy at anytime, but the created `UnsafeBufferPointer` still holds the address of the temporary region which may not be available at the time of calling `Data.init`.

So the contents of the `Data` can be any unexpected values, but, in your case, it seems to be all zero.

---

To avoid this sort of unexpected result, you should not pass an `inout` parameter to the argument of pointer which may be held after the method call.

In your case, a simple way is using the initializer of `Data` directrly.

Please try this code, and see what happens:

```
writeBatch.put(path.data(), value: Data(bytes: &owner.id, count: MemoryLayout<Int64>.size))
```

The initializer `Data.init(bytes:count:)` copies the contents in the temporary region before the region is release, so, it should hold the expected byte sequence containing the value of `owner.id`.

---

The first half of this answer applies to your *Working one*. So, it is not the right solution. (You know some wrong usage may generate an expected result by luck.)

Comment: The problem is that on the other hand Swift parameters are considered `let` constants and it is not possible to get an address of `let` constant so this involves triple copying of the argument, I hope that on the compiler level this kind of inefficiency is optimized out but having such code in my project looks creepy from a human perspective